# Código PHP para consultar MYSQL vazando memória

Tags: php, mysql, memória

Tudo bom pessoal? Pessoal estou com um problema que ainda não tinha me deparado antes. Escrevi o código abaixo e na hora de abrir a página pelo localhost no navegador ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\site_almoxarifado_testes\controle_material.php on line 1

Controle do Estoque

```
<body id="corpo">
    <header id="cabecalho">

    </header>
    <section id="titulo_principal">
        <form method="post" action="funcoes.php">
            <input type="text" name="pesquisar" size="126" placeholder=" exp: cabo 4mm ...">
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
        </form>
        <nav id="menuTabela">
            <ul type="disc">
                <li><a class="tabela" href="controle_material.php">Id's das Cidades</a></li>
                <li><a class="tabela" href="controle_notas.php">Nome das Cidades</a></li>
                <li><a class="tabela" href="saida_material.php">Estados</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="principal">
            <table id="tabela2">
                <?php if (isset($pesquisar)) {
                    while ($rows_cursos = $resultado_busca->fetch_assoc($resultado_busca)) {
                        echo utf8_encode($rows_cursos['nome_cidade']);
                    }
                } else { while ($colunas = $selecao_geral->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="td"><?php echo utf8_encode($colunas['idcidade']); ?></td>
                            <td id="td1"><?php echo utf8_encode($colunas['nome_cidade']); ?></td>
                            <td id="td2"><?php echo utf8_encode($colunas['uf']); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }
                 } ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside>

    </aside>
    <footer id="rodape">

    </footer>
    <?php $conecta->close(); ?>
</body>
```

Este é o código do funcoes.php

```
include 'controle_material.php';

define("SERVIDOR", "localhost");
define("USUARIO", "root");
define("SENHA", "");
define("BANCODEDADOS", "controle_almoxarifado");

$conecta = new mysqli(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA, BANCODEDADOS);

if ($conecta->connect_error) {
    trigger_error("ERRO NA CONEXÃO: " . $conecta->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];

//$pesquisa_tabela = mysqli_query($conecta, 'select * from cidade where nomes like %pedro%');
$selecao_geral = mysqli_query($conecta, "select * from cidade");

$resultado_busca = mysqli_query($conecta, "select * from cidade where nome_cidade like %$pesquisar%");
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Bom, não sei o quanto de memória é necessário para alocar essa sua consulta, mas para corrigir esse seu problema você pode tanto aumentar o limite de memória a ser usado pelo php.ini ou simplesmente usar o `ini_set` para setar o seu limite de memória em tempo de execução

```
<?php
    ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
?>
```

onde o '256M' representa a quantidade de memória, em MegaBytes, a ser utilizada.

O `ini_set` define um novo valor para a opção de configuração indicada. A opção de configuração irá manter o novo valor durante a execução do script e será restaurado ao final da execução do script.[Veja mais aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: Opa! Não resolveu, mas vi o motivo do excesso de memória utilizado. Fuçando para resolver, consegui fazer carregar a página, e quando a página apareceu ela estava abrindo várias vezes a mesma tabela repetidas vezes dentro da mesma página tipo um loop.